# UIImageView stretched incorrectly while using UITableViewAutomaticDimension

Tags: ios, uitableview, uiimageview

I have a table which has `UITableViewAutomaticDimension` turned on to automatically calculate height of each cell. Auto layout is turned on.

The table has custom cells. Each of these cells contains an image (`UIImageView`)

The first time the table is shown an image which is visible on the screen is stretched vertically.

The rest of the images are ok (not stretched).
If I scroll down (so the first image become invisible) and scroll back up to see it again then the image will become normal (not stretched)

It looks like for some reason iOS doesn't calculate the height of first image correctly.

Have you seen anything like it? Do you know how to fix it?

I tried to use different Mode for UIImageView (Aspect Fit, Aspect Fill). I can get it to be correctly looking. However, the cell itself is still stretched (much taller than it should be).

P.S. I tried to create a separate project to duplicate this problem in the clean environment and I can't find that something which causing the error.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This sounds like it could be caused by the original image in the UIImageView having large dimensions to begin with and then the `UITableViewAutomaticDimension` getting confused. Have you tried using the same image for every row or using a smaller image that fits the dimensions of the `UIImageView`?

You stated

> If I scroll down (so the first image become invisible) and scroll back up to see it again then the image will become normal (not stretched)

This is most likely because of the tableview reusing the cells via the `UITableView`'s `dequeueReusableCellWithIdentifier` meaning that instead of recreating a new cell every time you want a cell displayed it get's one from the stack of already created cells and uses that one (mainly to save memory). Additionally this could be caused by an auto-layout issue (maybe there is a constraint not being set or there is constraint overlap and XCode tries to fix the issue by breaking one or more constraints)

Also you never stated whether the issue is for `Objective-C` or `Swift`.

Comment: You was right. The root cause was UIImageView which was larger than screen. I had a resize logic to make sure that picture has a width equal to the whole screen. I used cell.bonnds.width to resize a picture and apparently it was wider than a screen initially.

Answer (score 0):

First, make sure you have to set all left, right, bottom, and top constraints attached to the cell containerView, so autolayout can do its work

Second, you have to set estimatedRowHeight to something different than 0. If you don't do this, auto layout will not calculate the cell's height.

```
// Something like this should be fine
tableView.estimatedRowHeight = 44.0
```

Answer (score 0):

Try to fix your Top,Bottom,leading,trailing constrains.. 
If you want to fix height,width of your image then also set height,width constrains.

This will solve your problem.